# Trying to incorporate the mass of a ball

Tags: python

I'm having trouble trying to incorporate mass into my program (specifically, the mass of a basketball).

So, first off, I used an equation to determine what the ball's velocity has to be in order to go through the hoop (with gravity factored in).  When I ran my program with just gravity, it went through the hoop perfectly, no problems.

However, when I try an incorporate the mass of the ball, it completely misses the hoop (which, of course, can be expected, I suppose).  I'm just unsure about how I used my equations.  Can anyone here just clear up if I'm on the right track?

```
rim = ring(pos= vector(-0.6,-0.7,0), radius = 0.46, axis= vector(0,1,0))

basketball = sphere(pos= vector(-4.9,-2,0), radius = 0.12, color = color.orange)
basketball.velocity = vector(4.53, 6.01, 0)

g = -9.8
timeStep = 0.005
basketball.mass = 0.623 #got this from the internet, in kg


for x in arange(0, 3, 0.005):
    basketball.velocity.y = basketball.velocity.y + (g/basketball.mass)*timeStep
    basketball.pos = basketball.pos+basketball.velocity*timeStep
    rate(100)
```

Don't mind the position of the rim, there are reasons behind its position not being 0 everywhere.  I guess all I'm really asking is if, given that the velocity of the ball is correct, the mass of the ball is being incorporated in the program correctly.  And if not, what are some steps I can take to make it work right?

Comment: Erm.. what leads you to believe the mass of the ball has anything to do with how it'll move in the air?  [Aside: your velocity increment doesn't work dimensionally.  Think of what the units are on the second term.]

Comment: Galileo did this experiment in the 16th century from the leaning tower of Pisa. Sound familiar? You know, the one where he dropped balls of different masses off the tower?

Comment: The experiment was also duplicated on the moon, when the astronaut dropped a hammer and a feather - without air to slow down the feather, they both hit the ground/moon at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

If you're modeling the physics of your program, you need to think a little more clearly about how you want the ball's mass to influence motion. Simply adding mass as a factor in the motion will not be an accurate representation of physics since (as DSM pointed out in a comment under your question) mass has nothing to do with motion. You could possibly consider something else such as momentum or kinetic energy but I'm not sure if that's the kind of complexity you want to incorporate.

**EDIT**:
Some advice - do not jump straight into coding your application right away and think about how you want to model the physics first. Once you have that figured out, you can begin coding it.

**EDIT 2 (EDIT 3 - corrected the last equation)**:
If you've specified the initial velocity to be `vector(4.53, 6.01, 0)`, then you can consider how changing the mass will affect it by calculating the kinetic energy. Let's assume that you always launch the ball with fixed energy **E**. Therefore:

```
E = 0.5 * m * v^2:
2E/m = v^2
```

This means that v is proportional to `1/m^0.5` or `1/(square root of m)`. Therefore, the new launch velocity `V` for a new mass `M` would be:

```
V = (m/M)^0.5 * v
```

To illustrate with an example: increasing the mass by 4 times the original would result in an initial launch velocity that's half as much as the previous launch velocity.

Comment: I had a pretty clear understanding of what I wanted to do, especially from a physics standpoint.  I was told that I should include mass after I'd done all initial calculations, so it kind of threw me off.  If the mass of the ball doesn't really matter, then I guess my problem is solved.

Comment: For a ball that's already in motion, it doesn't. But if the motion of the ball has to be initiated in your program somewhere as well (for example, by launching, etc.) then you could possibly incorporate mass as a factor that affects initial launch velocity.

Comment: Basically, basketball.velocity = vector(4.53, 6.01, 0), tells me the initial velocity in the x and y direction that the ball has to have in order to go through a hoop that's 4.3 m away and 3 m high (minus the initial height of the ball, which would be however tall the player holding it is).  If I incorporate mass, how will these values change?

Comment: "Incorporate mass" by itself doesn't mean anything, though; you'd need to be more specific.  For the reasons given by Paul McGuire, the mass of the ball cancels out from the standard just-gravity kinematic equations.  If you specify the initial velocity (so that you're not computing it from someone's throwing force and throw time, for example, in which the ball's mass could play a role), then the only way mass could come into play is if there's another force in the problem you haven't mentioned, like an air drag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this part of the problem, there isn't any force that I haven't mentioned. I guess the question was just worded in a weird way. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: If you are considering the launch velocity in your program, then mass can possibly affect it if you consider kinetic energy. For illustration, I've added some details in an update on my answer.

Comment: @Dawood: you've got it backwards.  For fixed E, increasing the mass must *lower* the initial velocity.

Answer (score 3):

The mass of the basketball is already incorporated into the constant 9.8.  This is basic Physics:

```
F = ma
```

so to solve for a

```
a = F/m
```

The gravitational force is found by `F = G m1 * m2 / r**2`, where G is the gravitational constant.

If m1 is the mass of the earth and m2 is the mass of the basketball, then `a = G * m1 * m2 / r**2 / m2` - that is, m2 cancels out, so `a = G * m1 * r**2`, which means that for all everyday values of m2, a is the same!  (The earth also accelerates ever so slightly towards the basketball, but this term is usually neglected.)

```
G = 6.67300 * 10**-11 (gravitational constant)
m1 = 5.9736 * 10**24 (mass of earth in kg)
r = 6.371 * 10**6 (radius of earth in meters)
```

Substituting into `G * m1 / r**2` gives:

```
>>> 6.673e-11 * 5.9736e24 / (6.371e6**2)
9.8206911462951823
```

QED

Comment: So, for all practice purposes, the mass of the ball can just be completely ignored?

Comment: the mass of the ball comes into play if you are trying to calculate the initial velocity using 1/2(m.v^2), once you get the v, the only thing that matters in a free fall is the acceleration i.e. g

Comment: Unless the mass of the basketball becomes a significant fraction of the mass of the earth, yes, you can ignore it.

Comment: Well I think I'd disagree. Its probably not about how massive is the second object. As you mentioned above that m2 cancels out. So m2 does not matter at all. However, what matters is that the object is close to the earth and you can replace the general r with R(radius of earth)

Comment: However if m2 becomes very big, then earth would accelerate significantly towards it too. Then we'd for sure miss the ring if we don't take this effect into consideration :)

Answer (score 1):

Your units for the velocity are inconsistent

g : m/(s^2)
m : kg

```
(g/basketball.mass)*timeStep
```

This would make the units : m/(kg.s) **(inconsistent)**

You probably need to look into the equation of motions

v = u + at

where 
v = final velocity
u = initial velocity
a = acceleration , in you case it would be g
t = The time for which a constant force is applied and hence it maintains g over that period of time

Comment: Should I be multiplying by the mass of the ball, then?  What can I do to make the units consistent?